# PHPUnit stub returns unexpected NULL value

Tags: php, phpunit

> **Note**: I am attempting to stub out a [\HTML5](https://github.com/Masterminds/html5-php) object for use within one of my tests.

When mocking the `loadHTML()` method and setting a return value, the value is returned as NULL.

```
/** Set up my expectations **/
$stub = $this->getMock("\HTML5");
$stub->expects($this->once())
     ->method("loadHTML")
     ->with("some data")
     ->will($this->returnValue("Some Value"));
```

The above sets up the expectation that calling `\HTML5::loadHTML("some data")` will return the string `Some Value`. Let's call this method.

```
var_dump($stub->loadHTML("some data")); // NULL
```

Calling `loadHTML()` shows `NULL` as the return value.

Why is my expected value not being returned? Is this a bug? An issue with the library I am using?

- The `\HTML5` object does not have a specific [constructor](https://github.com/Masterminds/html5-php/blob/master/src/HTML5.php) implementation, so I do not need to call `disableOriginalConstructor()` on the `$stub` object to bypass this.
- The `loadHTML()` [method](https://github.com/Masterminds/html5-php/blob/master/src/HTML5.php#L74) only takes a string as it's parameter, which I am including.

I am using:

- **PHP 5.4.9**
- **PHPUnit 3.7.28**
- **My Brain**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`loadHTML()`](https://github.com/Masterminds/html5-php/blob/master/src/HTML5.php#L74) method is a **static method**. In PHPUnit, you do not set up mock static method expectations with `expects()`; you must use `staticExpects()` instead.

The reason this was not immediately prelevant is because PHP allows static methods to be called as one would do a normal method if the object encapsulating those methods has been instantiated.

I had already created the `\HTML5` object, hence the static method could be called with a `->` instead of the usual `::` you can use without object instantiation.

In 2010, Sebastian Bermann [wrote a post](http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/883-Stubbing-and-Mocking-Static-Methods.html) describing a new `staticExpects()` method available in **PHPUnit 5.3+**.

Here is the code above re-written to use the static method:

```
$stub = $this->getMock("\HTML5");
$stub->staticExpects($this->once())
     ->method("loadHTML")
     ->with("some data")
     ->will($this->returnValue("Some Value"));

var_dump($stub->loadHTML("some data")); // "Some Value"
```

In conclusion, just *don't write static methods in your own code*. It will make other developer's testing (like mine) much harder to deal with having to go into the source code of an external library to understand why I couldn't test my code by mocking out theirs.